# What is The number of subnet for the IP Address with CIDR Notation : 172.20.0.0/27

Tags: networking

What is The number of subnet for the IP Address with CIDR Notation : 172.20.0.0/27. As far i know if we Use CIDR notation then it is called classless routing and the subnet mask is calculated according to on bit and off bit. So According to this rule the number of subnet is 2^3=8 .

But When we think this IP as class B then the Number of subnet is 2048.

I have confusion regarding this which one is correct??? So can anyone help me regarding this. What is the right way to calculate number of subnet, when given CIDR notation???

Comment: So stop thinking of it as class B. It isn't. It is CIDR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are 8 * 256 = 2048 subnets.  172.x.x.x is class B which has /16 (Today, the Internet is classless, but I think the academic world has not caught up):

```
172.20.0.0/27
172.20 .0  .xxx00000
255.255.255.11100000
------- -------
   16  + 11 = /27
172.20 .0  .00000000 |
172.20 .0  .00100000 |
172.20 .0  .01000000 |
172.20 .0  .01100000 | 8
172.20 .0  .10000000 |
172.20 .0  .10100000 |
172.20 .0  .11000000 |
172.20 .0  .11100000 |
                         *
172.20 .1  .00000000   |
    ...                |
172.20 .2  .00000000   |  256
    ...                |
172.20 .3  .00000000   | 
...                    |
172.20 .255  .00000000 |
    ...
```

Comment: Online IP Calculator also showing the result according to Class B. That is why i am confused about the issue, Which one is correct?

Comment: CIDR implies classless, whereas "subnets" implies classfull.  But it says CIDR "notation" only, not a CIDR "block".  The idea is to know how to subdivide networks--that math is still applicable today.

Comment: "the subnet mask is calculated according to on bit and off bit. So According to this rule the number of subnet is 2^3=8 "  seems like flawed logic.  How did you get 3 from classless and /27?